# Laravel testing not finding view provided by package

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-10

I have two Laravel packages: a package that represents the core and ui of an application. The core package depends on the ui package. In my core package, I want to test whether users with different roles can access a page.

The view that the controller (in the core package) method should return is part of the ui package.

```php
/** @testdox Users With 'User' Role Can Not Access The User Index Page */
public function test_users_with_user_role_can_not_open_user_index_page() : void
{
    $this->actingAs($this->user);

    $this->get(route('users.index'))->assertForbidden();
}

/** @testdox Users With 'Admin' Role Can Access The User Index Page */
public function test_users_with_admin_role_can_open_user_index_page() : void
{
    $this->actingAs($this->admin);

    $this->get(route('users.index'))->assertOk();
}
```

I register the service provider of my UI package in the base test case of the core package:

```php
protected function getPackageProviders($app) : array
{
    return [
        MyAppCoreServiceProvider::class,
        MyAppUIServiceProvider::class
    ];
}
```

In the `index` method of the `UserController` I return a view from the ui package:

```php
public function index() : View
{
    return view('my-app::admin.users.index');
}
```

The route definition (part of a group with the 'users' prefix):

```php
Route::get('', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
```

These views are registered in the service provider of the ui package:

```php
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', 'my-app');
```

When running my tests, I get the error on the second test:

> InvalidArgumentException: View [admin.users.index] not found.

When visiting the page through the browser, it works. Why would the view not be found when testing?

The file structure in my ui package is as follows:

```
| resources/
| -- views/
| ---- admin/
| ------ users/
| -------- edit.blade.php
| -------- index.blade.php
| -------- show.blade.php
```

I have tried:

- Clearing the view cache
- Removing the livewire component on the page

But the error remains.

Comment: makes somewhat sense, as you're not testing the ui package but the core package, the ui is not configured. You need to write an integration test that is testing both packages with each other. or perhaps make your life easier, and just test your project application for the three or four important things you have to test each time you run it and run those tests each tiime. let alone the function name, it feels all so wrong for a one-liner test.

Comment: The UI package service provider is registered in the base test case. This works for other views (like the login/registration page). These are returned in the exact same way and the test case that tests them extends the same base test case.

Comment: Why do you register them in the base test case? Those views aren't part of that package and should not be tested by it. But that might be unrelated to your issue, for that find and fix the typo. Triple check all names are as they should, namespaceing does not require extra-setup and view name resolution is as expected and verified.

Comment: @hakre Out of curiosity, which changes would you make to the testcase? Testing the access control of a page seems logical to me.

Comment: That's a good question! I would not do that with standard tests, perhaps application level tests that what you encoded works, e.g. more a behavioral test (and a test-suite for all of such kind), as you may want to test a) that access control is implemented and b) that it is with certain endpoints (routes in Laravel).  Therefore one test-case that verifies what you implemented works, and one test-case to test your configuration, e.g. all routes you require this with and all routes you do not require that with and that test-cases coverage should show at least for each router. Just my 2 cents.